Delimit the back-tick ` character in a string
I have a script that receives a password to decrypt a file. Some passwords have a single back tick ` character and the script fails with an incorrect password error. While testing using a hard-coded password, I found this password fails:
$Passwd = "StringWith`Character"

But that using this password works:
$Passwd = "StringWith``Character"

My question is: What PowerShell code will add an additional back tick? I tried:
$Passwd = "StringWith`Character"      # <-- entered by user
write-output "Passwd = $Passwd"
$new_pw = $Passwd.replace('`','``')
write-output "New_pw = $new_pw"

But the output I get is:
Passwd = StringWithCharacter
New_pw = StringWithCharacter

Confusingly, neither variable shows as having a back tick. This has me stumped. Any recommendations?

Slight progress. Using single quotes on the initial variable assignment allows the write-output to display the back tick in the original variable.

Your question is not about delimiting. It's about escaping the backtick. You should edit your question title - the current one is confusing, as it has nothing to do with the question you're asking.

⚠️ as an aside, in the interest of security, try to avoid handling (hardcoded) passwords in a script. The general approach of dealing with credentials is to avoid them and instead rely on other means to authenticate, such as certificates or Windows authentication

I agree about not using hardcoded passwords within a script. This was done to trace down which of the special characters like ~ ! > ) ` \ was the source of my problem.

It turns out the original variable assignment was the problem. I should have used single quotes instead of double quotes. This code:
$Passwd = 'StringWith`Character'      # <-- entered by user
$new_pw = $Passwd.replace('`','``')
write-output "Passwd = $Passwd"
write-output "New_pw = $new_pw"

Produces this output:
Passwd = StringWith`Character
New_pw = StringWith``Character


How is the user entering the password? No escaping would be needed if you were using Read-Host -AsSecureString

@SantiagoSquarzon, You are correct. It turns out I only had problems with the special character in the password while I was hard coding it within the script for testing.
